# How to escape shell metacharacters automatically with `find` command?

Tags: shell-script, find, quoting, wildcards

I've got a bunch of XML files under a directory tree which I would like to move to corresponding folders with the same name within that same directory tree.

Here is sample structure (in shell):

```
touch foo.xml bar.xml "[ foo ].xml" "( bar ).xml"
mkdir -p foo bar "foo/[ foo ]" "bar/( bar )"
```

So my approach here is:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c '
  DST=$(
    find . -type d -name "$(basename "{}" .xml)" -print -quit
  )
  [ -d "$DST" ] && mv -v "{}" "$DST/"' ';'
```

which gives the following output:

```
‘./( bar ).xml’ -> ‘./bar/( bar )/( bar ).xml’
mv: ‘./bar/( bar )/( bar ).xml’ and ‘./bar/( bar )/( bar ).xml’ are the same file
‘./bar.xml’ -> ‘./bar/bar.xml’
‘./foo.xml’ -> ‘./foo/foo.xml’
```

But the file with square brackets (`[ foo ].xml`) hasn't been moved as if it had been ignored.

I've checked and `basename` (e.g. `basename "[ foo ].xml" ".xml"`) converts the file correctly, however `find` has problems with brackets. For example:

```
find . -name '[ foo ].xml'
```

won't find the file correctly. However, when escaping the brackets (`'\[ foo \].xml'`), it works fine, but it doesn't solve the problem, because it's part of the script and I don't know which files having those special (shell?) characters. Tested with both BSD and GNU `find`.

Is there any universal way of escaping the filenames when using with `find`'s `-name` parameter, so I can correct my command to support files with the metacharacters?

Comment: For this situation, I would change direction, using `find` only to locate the files to handle, making it call a *script* (e.g., in Perl) that could handle the filenames without contaminating them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's so much easier with `zsh` globs here:

```
for f (**/*.xml(.)) (mv -v -- $f **/$f:r:t(/[1]))
```

Or if you want to include hidden xml files and look inside hidden directories like `find` would:

```
for f (**/*.xml(.D)) (mv -v -- $f **/$f:r:t(D/[1]))
```

But beware that files called `.xml`, `..xml` or `...xml` would become a problem, so you may want to exclude them:

```
setopt extendedglob
for f (**/(^(|.|..)).xml(.D)) (mv -v -- $f **/$f:r:t(D/[1]))
```

With GNU tools, another approach to avoid having to scan the whole directory tree for each file would be to scan it once and look for all directories and `xml` files, record where they are and do the moving in the end:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -mindepth 1 -name '*.xml' ! -name .xml ! \
  -name ..xml ! -name ...xml -type f -printf 'F/%P\0' -o \
  -type d -printf 'D/%P\0' | awk -v RS='\0' -F / '
  {
    if ($1 == "F") {
      root = $NF
      sub(/\.xml$/, "", root)
      F[root] = substr($0, 3)
    } else D[$NF] = substr($0, 3)
  }
  END {
    for (f in F)
      if (f in D) 
        printf "%s\0%s\0", F[f], D[f]
  }' | xargs -r0n2 mv -v --
)
```

Your approach has a number of problems if you want to allow any arbitrary file name:

- embedding `{}` in the shell code is **always** wrong. What if there's a file called `$(rm -rf "$HOME").xml` for instance? The correct way is to pass those `{}` as argument to the in-line shell script (`-exec sh -c 'use as "$1"...' sh {} \;`).
- With GNU `find` (implied here as you're using `-quit`), `*.xml` would only match files consisting of a sequence of valid characters followed by `.xml`, so that excludes file names that contain invalid characters in the current locale (for instance file names in the wrong charset). The fix for that is to fix the locale to `C` where every byte is a valid character (that means error messages will be displayed in English though).
- If any of those `xml` files are of type directory or symlink, that would cause problems (affect the scanning of directories, or break symlinks when moved). You may want to add a `-type f` to only move regular files.
- Command substitution (`$(...)`) strips *all* trailing newline characters. That would cause problems with a file called `foo␤.xml` for instance. Working around that is possible but a pain: `base=$(basename "$1" .xml; echo .); base=${base%??}`. You can at least replace `basename` with the `${var#pattern}` operators. And avoid command substitution if possible.
- your problem with file names containing wildcard characters (`?`, `[`, `*` and backslash; they are not special to the shell, but to the pattern matching (`fnmatch()`) done by `find` which happens to be very similar to shell pattern matching). You'd need to escape them with a backslash.
- the problem with `.xml`, `..xml`, `...xml` mentioned above.

So, if we address all of the above, we end up with something like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.xml' ! -name .xml ! -name ..xml \
  ! -name ...xml -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    base=${file##*/}
    base=${base%.xml}
    escaped_base=$(printf "%s\n" "$base" |
      sed "s/[[*?\\\\]/\\\\&/g"; echo .)
    escaped_base=${escaped_base%??}
    find . -name "$escaped_base" -type d -exec mv -v "$file" {\} \; -quit
  done' sh {} +
```

Phew...

Now, it's not all. With `-exec ... {} +`, we run as few `sh` as possible. If we're lucky, we'll run only one, but if not, after the first `sh` invocation, we'll have moved a number of  `xml` files around, and then `find` will continue looking for more, and may very well find the files we have moved in the first round again (and most probably try to move them where they are).

Other than that, it's basically the same approach as the zsh ones. A few other notable differences:

- with the `zsh` one, the file list is sorted (by directory name and file name), so the destination directory is more or less consistent and predictable. With `find`, it's based on the raw order of files in directories.
- with `zsh`, you'll get an error message if no matching directory to move the file to is found, not with the `find` approach above.
- With `find`, you'll get error messages if some directories cannot be traversed, not with the `zsh` one.

---

A last note of warning. If the reason you get some files with dodgy file names is because the directory tree is writable by an adversary, then beware than none of the solutions above are safe if the adversary may rename files under the feet of that command.

For instance, if you're using LXDE, the attacker could make a malicious `foo/lxde-rc.xml`, create a `lxde-rc` folder, detect when you're running your command and replace that `lxde-rc` with a symlink to your `~/.config/openbox/` during the race window (which can be made as large as necessary in many ways) between `find` finding that `lxde-rc` and `mv` doing the `rename("foo/lxde-rc.xml", "lxde-rc/lxde-rc.xml")` (`foo` could also be changed to that symlink making you move your `lxde-rc.xml` elsewhere).

Working around that is probably impossible using standard or even GNU utilities, you'd need to write it in a proper programming language, doing some safe directory traversal and using `renameat()` system calls.

All the solutions above will also fail if the directory tree is deep enough that the limit on the length of the paths given to the `rename()` system call done by `mv` is reached (causing `rename()` to fail with `ENAMETOOLONG`). A solution using `renameat()` would also work around the problem.

Comment: A highly complex solution that could be avoided if my proposal based on switching off globbing was used.

Comment: @schily, `set -f` is irrelevant here. There's no shell globbing in the OP's question. The problem here is the `fnmatch`ing performed by `find -name` when we would like it to do a byte-to-byte comparison, and `set -f` won't affect `find`'s behaviour.

Comment: Did you read the text from the OP? He mentions that there is no problem with escaping the `-name` argument but that there are problems with processing the `find` results using the shell.

Comment: @schily: You're confused. What OP ask is *escaping the filenames when using with find's -name parameter*. The problem is the using of `-name "$(basename "{}" .xml)"` inside inline-script. There, `basename` return something like `[ foo ]`, which contains pattern matching special characters, which the OP want to escape. There's nothing to do with shell globbing.

Comment: So you confirm that I am not confused and the OP has problems with the shell part that could be fixed via `set -f`.

Comment: @schily, please show how `set -f` could help or tell us where globbing is involved in the OP's code.

Comment: The problem here is the confused question from the OP that does not use a clean data flow and that makes it hard to give an easy to understand sample code. There is however a shell command involved and you could always introduce a shell command with `set -f; `. Maybe you could give a cleaner piece of code that could be used as a base for changes.

Comment: @schily, see my edit of the question. Does it make it clearer?

Comment: I don't see that this was a win. Note that the OP mentioned that he had no problems with introducing escapes in the `-name` argument for `find` but rather with the shell.

Answer (score 3):

When you use inline script with `find ... -exec sh -c ...`, you should pass `find` result to the shell through positional parameter, then you don't have to use `{}` everywhere in your inline script.

If you have `bash` or `zsh`, you can pass `basename` output through `printf '%q'`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec bash -c '
  for f do
    BASENAME="$(printf "%q" "$(basename -- "$f" .xml)")"
    DST=$(find . -type d -name "$BASENAME" -print -quit)
    [ -d "$DST" ] && mv -v -- "$f" "$DST/"
  done
' bash {} +
```

With `bash`, you can use `printf -v BASENAME`, and this approach won't work properly if file name contains control characters or non-ascii characters.

If you want it to work properly, you need to write a shell function to escape only `[`, `*`, `?` and backslash.

Comment: `printf '%q'` will not escape all characters in the proper way for `find`'s `-name`. Like for control characters or some non-ascii characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Why do we need to escape other characters? I think `[`, `*` and `?` are enough.

Comment: `printf  '%q'` is a ksh93 enhancement that is not part of POSIX. It will not work in portable scripts. `set -f` (see my answer) is portable.

Comment: @schily: Yes, I mention only `bash` and `zsh` there, `printf '%q'` in `ksh93` won't work in this case. How can you make `find` aware about `set -f`?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, you only want to escape `[`, `*` and `?` while `printf %q` will escape others, like it will change a newline character to `$'\n'` which for `find -name` is `$'n'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ah, right, that's the point. Make the editing. So writing a shell function to escape only those characters is the only way, maybe `awk`, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: See my answer: I was talking about the shell,, the `find` command is not even affected by `set -f` in case it is built into the shell (as e.g. true for the recent Bourne Shell versions). `set -f` affects file name expansion for shell command arguments.

Comment: @schily: I know, but it does not help in this case. And you can just double quote to disable globbing for the shell.

Comment: The question is not really clean, it uses `sh -c` in the exec call. I expect things to work, in case this shell command is modified to switch off file name globbing first

Answer (score 2):

The good news:

```
find . -name '[ foo ].xml'
```

is not interpreted by the shell, it is passed this way to the find program. Find however interprets the argument to `-name` as a `glob` pattern and this needs to be taken into account.

If you like to call `find -exec \;` or better `find -exec +`, there is no shell involved.

If you like to process the `find` output by the shell, I recommend just to disable file name globbing in the shell by calling `set -f` before the code in question and switch it on again by calling `set +f` later.

Comment: `set -f` doesn't make any difference as `find` still can't find the file (`set -f; find . -name '[ foo ].xml'`) if I understood the answer correctly.

Comment: Well I mentioned that you should use `set -f` for shell commands that process the filenames. This is not the `find` command as `find` just produces the filenames.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question here. The OP is calling `find` within `find` with the argument to the `-name` of the second `find` being provided by the first `find` and transformed by a `shell`.

Comment: The OP is calling the shell with the names found by `find` and if the OP did use `set -f` as the first instruction in these shell commands, there would be no globbing and thus no resulting problems.

Comment: @schily, you're being confused, there's no shell globbing here.

Comment: It seems that you did not read the question from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a relatively straightforward, POSIX-compliant pipeline. It scans the hierarchy twice, first for directories and then for *.xml regular files. A blank line between scans signals AWK of the transition.

The AWK component maps basenames to destination directories (if there are multiple directories with the same basename, only the first traversal is remembered). For each *.xml file, it prints a tab-delimited line with two fields: 1) the file's path and 2) its corresponding destination directory.

```
{
    find . -type d
    echo
    find . -type f -name \*.xml
} |
awk -F/ '
    !NF { ++i; next }
    !i && !($NF".xml" in d) { d[$NF".xml"] = $0 }
    i { print $0 "\t" d[$NF] }
' |
while IFS='     ' read -r f d; do
    mv -- "$f" "$d"
done
```

The value assigned to IFS just before the read is a literal tab character, not a space.

Here's a transcript using the original question's touch/mkdir skeleton:

```
$ touch foo.xml bar.xml "[ foo ].xml" "( bar ).xml"
$ mkdir -p foo bar "foo/[ foo ]" "bar/( bar )"
$ find .
.
./foo
./foo/[ foo ]
./bar.xml
./foo.xml
./bar
./bar/( bar )
./[ foo ].xml
./( bar ).xml
$ ../mv-xml.sh
$ find .
.
./foo
./foo/[ foo ]
./foo/[ foo ]/[ foo ].xml
./foo/foo.xml
./bar
./bar/( bar )
./bar/( bar )/( bar ).xml
./bar/bar.xml
```

Comment: Nice, but it still doesn't allow arbitrary file names as it won't work if file paths contain TAB or newline characters (and potentially some other pathological cases as mentioned in my answer).