# Using for loop with find command

Tags: find, for

I want to read all java Versions on my system.

```
for i in 'find / -name java 2>/dev/null' 
do
echo $i checking
$i -version
done
```

I receive an error:

> find: paths must precede expression: 2>/dev/null
>
> Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're receiving that error from the `for` loop because your for loop is actually looping over *one* element -- the *string*, not the command: "`find / -name java 2>/dev/null`", so it is running:

```
echo find / -name java 2>/dev/null checking
find / -name java 2>/dev/null -version
```

... which is where `find`'s error arises.

You might be trying to do:

```
for i in `find / -name java 2>/dev/null` 
do
  echo $i checking
  $i -version
done
```

... (with backticks instead of single quotes), in which case I would suggest something more along the lines of:

```
find / -name java -exec sh -c '"$1" -version' sh {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Thanks to don_crissti for pointing out [Stéphane's better version of find ... exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262072/117549) and for indirectly reminding me of a bash method that is *one* better way to find and execute results than [looping over find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice):

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
for match in /**/java
do
  echo match is "$match"
  "$match" -version
done
```