# dynamic search of zip files in particular path and unzip it in same folder with the unzipped files?

Tags: shell-script

How can I do a dynamic search of zip files in a particular path (e.g.:`/opt/uploading/"*"/multiple .zip` files)
and unzip it into the same folder with the zip files?

Below function is unzipping multiple zip files and removing zip files.  But I want zip files to be there with the unzip files.

```
while true; do
   find -iname '*.zip' > zipindex
   test -s zipindex || break
   for zip in $(cat zipindex); do unzip -o $zip && rm $zip; done
done
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you'd like to extract all zip archives in the directory tree, and any zip files inside them, but avoid extracting the same file again? Doesn't that loop extract the archives in the current directory, instead of the location of the archive? Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I expect to extract all zip archives in the directory tree and any zip files inside them, but avoid extracting the same file again. but I need those unzipped files in a folder and zipped files in a folder so that we can avoid duplicates or else let me know how to handle the duplicates with these code.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `rm $zip` is removing the .Zip files, so remove it.

Comment: If I remove "rm $zip" the for loop continuously loop which is not correct.

Comment: Yes I see that. My mistake. But as long as they are there you will keep unzipping them. How often do you run this on the same dir?

Comment: whenever the .zip files arrive, so many times i do...

Answer (score 1):

This is much more suited for a for loop than a while loop. This way you can also get rid of the needless saving of results from `find -iname '*.zip' > zipindex`

Do something like this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for zip in $(find -iname '*.zip'); do
    unzip -o $zip
done
```

This will iterate through all of the lines that find produces.

Of course, you should just dispense with the bash script altogether and make a find oneliner like so:

`find -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \;`

EDIT: Thanks to @don_crissti and @ilkkachu, I've managed to get rid of calling another instance of the shell in -exec. -execdir is good to know!

Comment: [don't do that...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) - use `find` with `-exec`

Comment: I was just about to edit that in, actually @don_crissti :)

Comment: :) [don't do that either](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262072): _embedding `{}` in the shell code is always wrong._

Comment: Use `-execdir` to do the extraction in the directory containing the archive. Though this will still have problems with nested archives, the `find` might not find them all. (e.g. assume `z.zip` containing `a.zip` and that `find` sees the files in alphabetical order)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions! Although it can be a bit disheartening at times, (especially when you get reprimanded twice, he he) it is always **good** to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel you could do this:

```
find my_dir | grep -E '\.zip$' | parallel unzip
inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir | grep  -E '\.zip$' | parallel -u unzip
```

This way you do not need to busy wait for the next zip file to show up.